# Can a blind and possibly deaf baby rabbit be caged outside?

Tags: rabbits, outdoor, cage

We had to take in 7 wild baby bunnies, and we’re planning to release six of them and keeping the baby bunny that is missing both of its eyes. I guess that it was most likely born without them. Its eyes sockets are covered over with hair and there are clearly no eyes. I’m also concerned it might be deaf as well as it doesn’t startle as easily as its siblings.

I can tell it’s a girl and I’ve decided to name her Olive. If it turns out she is also deaf should I even give her an outside cage? I already have two domestic buns that live in a cage outside.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Are you sure, they are european rabbits? Or could they be cotton tailes? The second are not able to domesticate, as far as I know.

Comment: And please, add an aim or a real question to your post. The answers will focus and are more helpful for you!

Comment: If its potentially blind and deaf, and a baby, having a vet look at it seems like a very good idea

Comment: If there are birth defects and injuries you can see, there may be others you can't. Don't be heartbroken if this little one fails to thrive.

Answer (score -2):

Seems cruel to house a prey animal outside, in a cage, but outside where all sorts of animals that want to eat it can get near and try to get at it. And far more cruel to do that to a rabbit who can't see or hear any potential attacks, successful or not. Not like being able to see and hear what is starting to try to get at you, to eat you is the better option....

Rabbits are social animals. Not nice to house it alone in the backyard.  Rabbits can't defend themselves, and are delicious to tons of animals and humans.  Seems it's be a shity, lonely and frightening life for a blind, deaf rabbit stuck off somewhere away from any family.

Comment: The OP writes, that they have already two bunnies outside. So this one would not be alone.